# How to set items per page dropdown in grid view for yii

Tags: yii

I want to set items per page dropdown in yii gridview.

What changes i need to do this? Has anyone had implemented this type of functionality before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `summaryText` entry to the gridview as below.

```
$pageSize=Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider_countries,
'summaryText'=>'Displaying {start}-{end} of {count} result(s). ' .
  CHtml::dropDownList(
    'pageSize',
     $pageSize,
     Yii::app()->params['pageSizeOptions'],
     array('class'=>'change-pageSize')) .' rows per page',
```

Result is similar to following.
[image]